# Node request/connection-specific variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

**Context:**

I'm trying to link log entries to the request associated with the generation of those entries. I like the concept of bunyan's `child` logger, which allows me to attach a request id to any later entries made by the child logger. I wanted this logger to be used in other modules, so I `require` a file with a getter to get the child logger. This allows an otherwise isolated event such as `getting widgets` to be linked to the request that caused that entry

Contrived example:

`index.js`

```
var widget = require('./widget');
var logging = require('./logging');
//...
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
    var logger = logging.getLogger();
    var child = logger.child({requestId: req.id}); //req.id set in earlier middleware
    logging.setLogger(child);
};
app.get('/widgets', function(req, res, next) { 
    res.json(widgets.getAll());
};
//...
```

`widget.js`

```
var logging = require('./logging');
//...
exports = module.exports = {
    getAll: function () {
        logging.getLogger().info("getting widgets");
        return widgets;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the state is shared between requests (singletons?), so if two requests are made nearly simultaneously, the "getting widgets" log entry will have the `requestId` property set to the second request's id.

**The question:**

Is there a way to have variables whose scope is attached to the request, without having to inject and pass around the `req` object (e.g. `new widget()` and/or `widget.setRequest(req)`), or instantiating as injecting the `logging` object? Passing objects like this into other modules feels like violating separation of concerns

Put another way, what is the best way to share state for a request, rather than across requests, to implement what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: `logging.setLogger(logging.getLogger().`... my eyes are starting to burn. I've never seen such verbose node.js before x.x

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it was a pretty contrived example just to get the point across. recommendations? would more lines help?

Comment: I can't find any documentation that references `req.id`. Where is that coming from?

Comment: it doesn't exist by itself, it is generated in a prior middleware and added to the `req` object (in the `//...` lines somewhere)

Comment: And to make sure I understand the general goal, it's to have console logs that are prefixed with the unique request ids?

Comment: Basically. Not necessarily console logs or prefixes, but yes, a log entry with a `requestId` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each request its own private child logger by changing your code to:

```
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) { 
    req.fooBarLogger = logging.getLogger().child({requestId: req.id});
});
app.get('/widgets', function(req, res, next) { 
    res.json(widgets.getAll(req));
});
```

---

```
module.exports = {
    getAll: function(req) {
        req.fooBarLogger.info("getting widgets");
        return widgets;
    }
};
```

Comment: Darn, beat me to it... I was halfway through explaining the same thing. Here was my logic: My thought is that, if you need console logs that are affiliated with a particular request object, rather than storing references inside the `logging` module, you can attach it directly to the `req` object since any console log affiliated with that `req` will more than likely have scope access to that `req` object.

Comment: I had this in my question "without having to inject and pass around the req object". It gets more complicated when the dependencies of widgets have further dependencies, which then also need the `req` object, or when widget doesn't need it, but its dependencies do. That's why it seems like it violates SoC principles. If injecting it to all the dependencies and subdependencies is the only way to get the functionality that I'm hoping for, I guess I'll just have to accept it

Comment: You don't have to attach it to `req`. For example, you could just pass it around directly. However, that would then require *all* functions that need to do logging to now take yet another parameter -- which is even more complicated and not always possible. Hanging the logger off of the `req` object is generally the cheapest way to get what you want. Functions that already get passed the `req` object get the logger for free.